# Content Security Policy Internet explorer error

Tags: php, nginx, content-security-policy

I add Content-Security-Policy its work fine with Chrome, Firefox and Opera but with Internet Explorer 11 i have this error "This page can’t be displayed"

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "connect-src 'self' wss://example.com/ws/;
                                    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/recaptcha__en.js https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/cloudflare.min.js;
                                    frame-src 'self' https://www.terminal.com/embed/chart-widget/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/;
                                    img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://chart.googleapis.com https://shape.com;
                                    ";
```

if i comment this section its work with IE

Why i have this error only with IE ? Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy) content security policy is only partially supported through the X-Content-Security-Policy header, but not through the standard Content-Security-Policy header. Try using X-Content-Security-Policy header in IE...

Answer (score -1):

The issue is having new lines in your config block.

Make it a single config line and it should work fine.