# Implement Content Security Policy For Angular Application On Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

We are working on implementation of CSP(Content Security Policy) requirement in our application. We have set the CSP setting through the index.html using the meta tag :

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

which works fine in Chrome & Firefox. However, we need to implement this for Internet Explorer also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content Security Policy Internet explorer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736665/content-security-policy-internet-explorer-error)

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support CSP. At most you can use the `X-Content-Security-Policy` for IE 10 and newer. But this only supports the `sandbox` directive. Edge though should support most of what you need.

[Additional info on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy)

Comment: Thanks a lot Boris.. I tried to implement using X-Content-Security-Policy in the index.html in my Angular application with sandbox, but it is ignored.

Where and how are we supposed to set X-Content-Security-Policy in angular application for internet explorer.

Comment: The policy is used in the same way inside the meta tag like the one you used already. Unless I'm missing the point in your question.

Comment: I tried to implement it in the same way with sandbox but its not working on internet explorer.

Comment: That's the point, IE only supports that, so you can't really solve it. Edited response for clarification.